# How to run two blackberry simulators on same PC

Tags: java

When I run two blackberry 7.1.0 simulators on same machine, in one of the simulator it complains `could not open port 19780 and it is use by another program.....` despite fact I made changes in data-port values in **.bat** files, **rimpublic.property** files inside MDS and **fledge-settings.conf** in simulator. But all this changes doesn't reflect in my simulator.
If anyone has already experience about this problem, kindly help me to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another approach: Use virtual machines (e.g. VmWare).

This way you can run as many simu as you like.

Also, most likely two BB phones communicate with each other via network, so placing BB simu instances on different virtual machines may unleash potential problems with internet or network